# Scroll Buttons on a UIWebView

Tags: ios, button, uiwebview, scroll

So I'm trying to put two buttons on a UIWebView, a scroll up and a scroll down button. Ideally, the user will have the option to scroll through it with their finger, or by tapping the button. Like when they tap the button, it will scroll down an inch or so. I have no idea where to even start with this. I know I need to create two buttons, connect the outlets, then I'm lost from there. I have no idea what the function to cause the scroll would look like.

Update: I'm unsure of what to put in the `THE_DISTANCE_TO_SCROLL` area from the answer below. I have a feeling that it should be a CGPoint, because when I type in an integer like 10 I get the error: `Sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the UIWebView has a property `scrollView` you can access that property in the methods that handle the button's tap and do something like:

```
//for scroll up
-(IBAction)scrollContentUp:(id)sender {
    [yourWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(yourWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.x,       
                          yourWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.y
                            -THE_DISTANCE_TO_SCROLL animated:YES)];
}

//for scroll down
-(IBAction)scrollContentDown:(id)sender {
  [yourWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(yourWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.x,       
                         yourWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.y
                         +THE_DISTANCE_TO_SCROLL animated:YES)];
}
```

You should also disable the buttons until the UIWebView is fully loaded (you can check this with UIWebView delegate methods)

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! and for the `THE_DISTANCE_TO_SCROLL` should I just type in an integer like 100 and play with it until I get it right? SOrry for the beginner questions!

Comment: Yes, you can type an integer (it should be a CGFloat but is converted) or you can calculate it depending on the UIWebView content size. Something like CGFloat distance = webView.scrollView.contentSize / webView.frame.size.height; in this way it should scroll with the screen heigth distance, something like a pagination (but is to much, the user will have hard time to follow the scroll, it is jut a simple example)

Comment: I actually got an error typing just an integer, it says  "Sending `double` to parameter of incompatible type `CGPoint` (aka `struct CGPoint`)". Ill try the code you posted above right now. Thanks again for helpin me through this!

Comment: It was a typo in my answer, the content offset is a CGPoint so the param to setContentOffset will be CGPointMake(0, webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x, THE_DISTANCE_TO_SCROLL);